# Pushing design changes to other views

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I have made a few cosmetic changes (background color, border, font size/color, etc.) to the headers of each column of a SharePoint list (allitems.aspx) using SharePoint designer 2010.  After getting it looking the way I like I went and created alternate filtered/grouped views of that list using the original as the starting place.  Unfortunately those stylistic changes did no propagate into the new views.

The requirement is that I make 8 separate views (just filtered differently) based on that original allitems view and I would rather not have to manually adjust each column header again.  Is there an easier way to push those style changes out to subsequent lists?  Maybe a template or some advanced process in SharePoint designer I do not know of?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use CSS to alter appearances, that way it will affect all views. Manually editing the view is not the way to do this unless you want to be repeating yourself.

Comment: ahhh...thank you.  I am just now getting into all this web design stuff so I'll try to figure out how to apply the CSS style from the fist view to the others.

Comment: No problem, just a tip for the Stack Exchange sites, if an answer solves/addresses the question hit the tick to accept it as an answer.